# What are some notable examples of novels that are only available in Esperanto?

Tags: literature

I am interested in better understanding the body of Esperanto literature.  Are there awards for notable books?  Which Esperanto novels hold special historical and cultural significance?  Are their older books from the beginning of the Esperanto movement which have withstood the "test of time" and are still highly regarded?

Comment: Please make only one question (or two if related) per topic. People can not know to which question someone is answering to.

Comment: I consider it one question; I was trying to provide possible ways to interpret "notable" so it wouldn't be flagged as too subjective.  Why does the form for submitting a question force one to add additional context to a question, if the goal is to keep it simple?  If that's what is desired, then the "headline" should be sufficient.

Comment: I think people were confused because you wrote the context in the form of questions that themselves could be seen as good SE questions. I'd love to see more questions by you, please don't feel discouraged.